# How to download and save a single file from QDeclarativeWebView

Tags: qt, webview, download, qml

I've being stuck on this one for ages, I wanted to download a .sis (Symbian installer) from QML WebView (Qt 4.7/4.8)

I have a QDeclarativeWebView class which I edited to fix the FileChooser and Javascript popup's, and which forwards download requests where it launches the default browser, that would all be hunkey dory but only pressing "Save Link" or "Save Images" triggers that, so I tried to forward unsupportedcontent with `connect(page, SIGNAL(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)));`
And `void unsupportedContent(const QNetworkReply& reply);` in Q_SIGNALS in the header

That just gives me this error

> Object::connect: No such slot QDeclarativeWebView::unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*) in C:/Users/me/StarBrowser/qdeclarativewebview.cpp:767

After that how would I go on to download and save the file ?

I know this has being asked a million times before but I've seen things about QHttp, using QNetworkAccessManager, but non of it really makes sense to me (I'm new to the whole Qt side of it all)

If anyone can help out on the problems it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error means that you have not declared suitable slot. Indeed,

```
Q_SIGNALS:
    void unsupportedContent(const QNetworkReply& reply);
```

should be replaced into

```
public slots:
    void unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply* reply) { ... };
```

Can u try to make connection after that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't quiet understand you, do I remove it from Q_SIGNALS ? I can't find an public slots bit in the header, here is the header, sorry it wouldn't let me paste the whole thing as a comment: http://allstarsoftware.x10.mx/header.txt

Comment: Can you say more concretely where signal and slot are declared? AFAIU, You use default signal fro QDeclarativePage and you have subclassed QDeclarativeWebView where you has declared your slot? Can you paste your slot declaration code? Can you check that it's signature suits signal's one? (I mean they both should have 1 arguument of QNetworkReply* type)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I totally forgot about this question, I have the unsupportedContent signal and things working now, I'm just stuck on the downloading and saving of a file when it fires the unsupportedContent, nothing I try seems to work, I only get errors. Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can u provide test example?

Comment: There isn't really much to show if I'm honest, I just tried using this as a downloader: http://www.allstarsoftware.x10.mx/qtdownload.rar I had a rather silly pot shot like this `Q_UNUSED(reply)
    qDebug() << "unsupported content";
    QtDownload::download(reply);`  But as expected it just said no matching function